# Split string and output into rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to split a string based on delimiter ',' and put the results into rows. Hence, I'm trying to use `SPLIT_TO_TABLE` function in Snowflake, but not working successfully.

I used the `regexp_replace` to clean the string. How can I output this into rows for each id?

```
SELECT value,
       TRIM(regexp_replace(value, '[{}_]', ' ')) AS extracted
```

**Here is the sample data:**

```
+--------+------------------------------------+
|   id   |               value                |
+--------+------------------------------------+
| fsaf12 | {Other Questions,Missing Document} |
| sfas11 | {Other}                            |
+--------+------------------------------------+
```

**Expected result:**

```
+--------+------------------+
|   id   |    extracted     |
+--------+------------------+
| fsaf12 | Other Questions  |
| fsaf12 | Missing Document |
| sfas11 | Others           |
+--------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HEre is answer , used replace function instead of regexp_replace

WITH DATATABLE(ID ,VALUEA ) AS
(

SELECT * FROM  VALUES  ('fsaf12','{Other Questions,Missing Document}'),('sfas11',' {Other} ')

)

SELECT ID, REPLACE(REPLACE(VALUE,'{',''),'}','') SPLITTED_VALUE FROM DATATABLE , LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE (VALUEA,',') ;

Answer (score 1):

Adding another way to split the data and output it as rows :

```
SELECT b,TRIM(regexp_replace(splitvalue, '[{}_]', '')) AS extracted from
(SELECT b, C.value::string AS splitvalue
FROM split,
     LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>split(a, ',')) C);
```

where a and b are the columns in table "split" and data is as follows :

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| {First,Second} | row1 |
| {Third,Fourth} | row2 |